# need to change product category page layout in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category-products

Check out
http://www.discountsignsupplies.com/products/removal-fluids

Under the product category title ("Removal Fluids") I need to...

1) Remove the header image
2) move the 5 images ABOVE the descriptive text/copy.

I have limited developer knowledge so hoping to do this as quickly and easily as possible, preferably via the admin if possible. I looked under CATEGORY > MANAGE CATEGORIES but nothing stood out for me.

Any help/thoughts?

Comment: do you want to make changes for this category only ?

Answer (score 1):

To make changes for your first question i.e. **Remove the header image** you need to follow the following steps.

1) Login to admin.

2) Navigate Catalog->Manage Categories.

3) Select your Category.

4) under general information you will find a field for image like below.
[image]

select delete image checkbox and save the category your image will get removed.

Now for second question i.e. **move the 5 images ABOVE the descriptive text/copy.** follow the following steps.

1) locate the file at `app\design\frontend\<YOUR_PACKAGE>\<YOUR_THEME>\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`

if you are not using any custom theme then you will get this file at `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`  or `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml`

2) in this file you will find a code like

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

near line no 56, just relocate this code at the bottom of file and your are done.

if you want this change for only this category then you need at the category condition over here so you file will become like

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View
 */
?>
<?php
    $_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();

    $_imgHtml   = '';
    if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
        $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    }
?>
<div class="page-title category-title">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>

<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>

<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    $categoryId = $_category->getId();
    if($categoryId != 3 && $_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>

<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
if($categoryId == 3 && $_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Where 3 is the category id which you can find out from admin when you click on category. like.

[image]

Hope this will help you.